# Vows: command not found

Tags: node.js, vows

I ran my tests from the root folder of my app. The tests lay within the spec directory.

```
$ vows  

No command 'vows' found, did you mean:
  Command 'vos' from package 'openafs-client' (universe)
  Command 'voms' from package 'voms-server' (universe)
vows: command not found
```

My package.json is as follows

```
{
  "author": "Sunil Kumar <sunilkumar.gec56@gmail.com>",
  "name": "subscription-engine-processor",
  "description": "Node.js server for Subscription Engine processor application.",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node index.js"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": ""
  },
  "main": "./index",
  "engines": {
    "node": "~0.6.6"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "buffers": "0.1.1",
    "redis": "0.7.1"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "vows": "0.6.x"
  }
}
```

I have done npm install so that the dependency modules including vows have been installed and are present in my node_modules/ directory.

Could any one please help me out as to what might be the issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The binary is not installed. You need to execute

```
npm install vows -g
```

NOTE: requires root privilege

the `-g` means to install it globally.

**EDIT:**
try

```
sudo npm config set dev true
```

before installation.

Comment: Tried installing globally  

    sudo npm install -g   

    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.1  
    npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers/0.1.1  
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/redis/0.7.1  
    npm http 304 https://registry.npmjs.org/buffers/0.1.1  
    subscription-engine-processor@0.0.0/usr/local/lib/node_modules/subscription-engine-processor  
    ├── buffers@0.1.1  
    └── redis@0.7.1  


The dependencies have been installed but not the development specific ones, i.e vows.

Comment: try `sudo npm config set dev true` before installation.

Comment: Is there any specific to run this so as to include global modules?   npm start complaints about the modules being not installed. Could you also please tell where are these modules installed?

Comment: If installed globally, the default location will be `/usr/lib/node_modules` (or `/usr/local/lib/node_modules` in some cases)

Answer (score 6):

You can also run the vows command from a local installation in the `node_modules` directory of your current project:

```
./node_modules/vows/bin/vows
```

EDIT: To be clear, `vows` is still a Node file, meaning that you would have to run it as a node program (rather than a standalone CLI tool). So, instead of being able to do this:

```
> vows -v tests.js
```

You'd have to do the following:

```
> node ./node_modules/vows/bin/vows -v tests.js
```